# Can't get Optimus to work with Ironhide on an Asus N53SN

Tags: nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics, intel, nvidia-optimus

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 (Same issue in 11.04 btw) and then I installed Ironhide.  I went through the configuration, chose the one with the highest confirmation for my system and tested it:

```
> Error: Module nvidia does not exist in /proc/modules
> P50 Disabling nVidia Card Succeded
```

(the spelling error is theirs)

And it changes nothing.  I tried other configurations and got worse results.  This has really become a major headache.  Any solutions?

Comment: Nothing has worked so far.  I got rid of the error saying module not found, but the success message is not true.

Comment: You may want to give the newer [Bumblebee](http://askubuntu.com/q/36930/6969#36936) a go which is more stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the solution to this is the following and with the latest updates to bumblebee, it works:

Install Bumblebee

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia

sudo usermod -a -G bumblebee $USER

Reboot or re-login

Answer (score 2):

try running .. and then reboot

```
rm /etc/pm/power.d/ironhide-disablecard-on-powerup
```

After reboot run `optirun glxgears.` See if it works,

Also I suggest using `xorg edgers ppa` to get latest module for nvidia

Comment: You said running .. running what?

Comment: I tried this.  It created no change.  It still says module not found.

Comment: I installed the nvidia proprietary drivers

Answer (score 1):

I had the same prob, installed PPA Xorg Edgers, ran `apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade`, reboot and magically it worked.